# Show hide Image overlay on hover Bootstrap 4.2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, opacity

I am using `Bootstrap 4.2.` What is the preferred method of showing and hiding an Image overlay with a smooth transition.

My HTML structure will be:

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img src="..." class="card-img" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with [Display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/display/)? So I am able to use responsive classes. Because I don't want the hover effect on mobile.

And I can't find the `opacity` class anymore in `Bootstrap 4.2.`?

Comment: on mobile devices hover effect is shown when you click on the image .. you want to remove that also??

Comment: You can always overwrite any css properties using media queries. What's your problem?

Comment: Check out some examples on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp. To hide overlay on mobile try something like this: @media (max-width: 768px) { .overlay { display: none;} }

Comment: @emix I know I can overwrite with custom CSS, but I thought maybe there is a Bootstrap way to do it? And what about the `fade effect` in Bootstrap 4.2 where is that for?

Comment: Provide all the code related to the issue.

Comment: I fix it by writing custom CSS in combination with [Bootstrap cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/card/#image-caps).

Comment: If you fixed it, post the answer and accept it!

Comment: Try to use CSS opacity property.

Answer (score 0):

I am preferred method of showing and hiding an Image overlay with a smooth transition in your code using simple css & html code.

```css
.uvs {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.card-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;color:#fff;
}
.uvs:hover .card-img-overlay {  
  opacity: 1;
}  .card-uvs{ position: absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:20%; -webkit-transform: translate(-10%, -10%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-10%, -10%);
  transform: translate(-10%, -10%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="uvs"> <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/paris.jpg" class="card-img" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay"> <div class="card-uvs">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
  </div>  </div>
</div></div>
```